# How to integrate kanboard with telegram?

Tags: python, https, certificate, telegram

I have to integrate https://kanboard.org with Telegram.

I want to be able to manage projects, tasks, and subtasks, start and stop a timer on subtasks, get notifications if new projects, tasks, and subtasks have been received from another person, notifications what deadlines you have today,  notifications that a user has a deadline tomorrow via Telegram

I've read the documentation of the telegram and kanboard.
The problems are as follows:

1. I have a certificate.pem for https for kanboard, but it doesn't work (code (1))
     1.1. an Error pops up (code (2) )
     1.2. or this error pops up. (code (3) )
2. When I disable https and leave just http for kanboard, it does not respond to my tasks that I set to. It runs without errors, but it still does not do anything even with using the jsonrpc user with a correct API (code (4) )

(1)

```
import requests

requests.get('https://board.rgray.io', verify='/Users/Katty/Desktop/certificate.pem')
```

(4)

```
from kanboard import Kanboard

kb = Kanboard("https://board.rgray.io/jsonrpc.php", "jsonrpc", "API")


project_id = kb.create_project(name="PythonTest")
kb.add_project_user(project_id=project_id, user_id=123, role='project-manager');

task_id = kb.create_task(project_id=project_id, title="My task title")
```

(2)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 267, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs)
ssl.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:4053)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 269, in ssl_wrap_socket
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:4053)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Katty/Documents/all/coding/python/kanboard_tgbot/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    requests.get('https://board.rgray.io', verify='/Users/MillerProduction/Desktop/certificate.pem')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: unknown error (_ssl.c:4053)
```

(3)
`<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>`

Comment: try `requests.get('https://board.rgray.io', verify='/Users/Katty/Desktop/certificate.pem', verify=False)`

Comment: File "/Users/Katty/Documents/all/coding/python/kanboard_tgbot/test2.py", line 3
    requests.get('https://board.rgray.io', verify='/Users/Katty/Desktop/certificate.pem', verify=False)
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated